# jQuery - attribute vs. property

Tags: jquery, attributes, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Is there a difference between an `attribute` and a `property` in the `jQuery` terminology? Is there an example that can clarify this point?

Comment: take a look at docs: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 9):

> Is there a difference between an attribute and a property in the jQuery terminology?

Yes, there is a difference.

For example...

```
<input type="text" name="age" value="25" />
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmBVU/).

The attribute would be the `value` attribute as in the markup. You would use `attr('value')`.

The property would be the `value` property as accessed via the DOM API. You would use `prop('value')` (strictly speaking, you'd use `val()`).

Sometimes they can be very similar, but not always.